# Cannot use background element in style tag in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-drawable, android-styles

I am trying to apply a custom style to a textview in android using styles. Unfortunately I am getting this exception at runtime:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #59 in com.myapp.android:layout/fragment_draw: Binary XML file line #59 in com.mirana.android:layout/fragment_draw: Error inflating class TextView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #59 in com.mirana.android:layout/fragment_draw: Error inflating class TextView
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.mirana.android:drawable/drawable_button_background_filled with resource ID #0x7f080482
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 0 to dimension: type=0x4
```

**draw_layout_frag.xml**

```
 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/btn_clear"
  style="@style/buttonDrawSectionTypeFilledStyle"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Clear" />
```

**themes.xml**

```
 <item name="drawableButtonBgDrawSectionFilled">@drawable/drawable_button_background_filled</item>
```

**attrs.xml**

```
 <attr name="drawableButtonBgDrawSectionFilled" format="reference" />
```

**style.xml**

```
 <style name="buttonDrawSectionTypeFilledStyle">
    <item name="android:background">?attr/drawableButtonBgDrawSectionFilled</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/_40sdp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?attr/colorBaseRed</item>
</style>
```

**drawable_button_background_filled.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <corners android:radius="12dp" />
  <stroke
    android:width="4dp"
    android:color="?attr/colorBaseRed" />
</shape>
```

My question here is, is it not possible to use background element in styles or am I doing something wrong in the code ?

Comment: please share the fragment_draw layout, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's complicated to set style to textView, you can try below method to do that

1. `TextView myStyledTextView = new TextView(this, null, 0, R.style.my_style);`
2. `TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(textView, android.R.style.TextAppearance_DeviceDefault_Small);` (Compat version)
3. `TextView myText = (TextView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tvstyle, null);`

Answer (score 0):

What is the shape? You wrote:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<corners android:radius="12dp" />
<stroke
   android:width="4dp"
   android:color="?attr/colorBaseRed" />
</shape>
```

But no type `android:shape=["rectangle" | "oval" | "line" | "ring"] >`
[please look here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#Shape)